# Lightning app builder embeded with blank vf page calling another vf page on load not working as expected

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-builder

I have a requirement where spacing shown due to app builder embeded with vf page should be gone.For that i tried by creating a vf page calling the required vf page on load.

However while doing it I have facing these issues explained with images.First time when the user logins ,he sees the image 1,which clearly has spaces which i don't intent to show.

Image 2 has clearly no spaces or the labels (which i dont want to show) but it happens when i choose the filter to show different records and the page is loaded again but it doesnt show the lower scroll bar which comes in Image 3.

Controller

```
public class PriceManager_Grid {

public PageReference CallPriceManagerGrid() {
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/gblite__Grid?gname=Quote Approvals For Price Manager');
    pr.setredirect(true);
  return pr;
}
```

}

Vf page

```
   <apex:page controller="PriceManager_Grid" action="{!CallPriceManagerGrid}">
```

[image: This is the image when user logins and see this as Homepage]
[image: This is the image when user changes the filter..No the excess space is gone but the scroll bar on the lower goes off]
[image: This the page when the spacing is gone means the vf page is called and the lower scroll bar also comes up]